# Juntemos [navegador-web] y [webbrowser] y otras etiquetas también separadas innecesariamente

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Estas dos etiquetes se definen igual y se usan para lo mismo:

- [navegador-web](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navegador-web)
- [webbrowser](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webbrowser)

Urge juntarlas: [webbrowser](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webbrowser) → [navegador-web](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navegador-web).

Y ya que estamos:

- Cambiar el nombre de [geo-localizacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geo-localizacion) → [geolocalización](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geolocalizaci%c3%b3n).
- Juntar: [config](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/config) → [configuración](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/configuraci%c3%b3n).
- Juntar: [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/link) e [hyperlink](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyperlink) → [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enlace).
- Juntar: [interface](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interface), [interfaz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interfaz) y [interfaz-gráfica](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interfaz-gr%c3%a1fica).
- Juntar: [radio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio) y [radiobutton](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radiobutton) (¿y [radiogroup](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radiogroup)?).
- Juntar: [groupby](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groupby) → [agrupación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agrupaci%c3%b3n).
- Juntar: [session](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session) → [sesiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sesiones).
- Juntar: [carousel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/carousel) → [carrusel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/carrusel).
- Juntar: [depurar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depurar) y [debug](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debug) → [depuración](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depuraci%c3%b3n).
- Juntar: [validation](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validation) → [validación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validaci%c3%b3n).
- Juntar: [ficheros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ficheros) y [archivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/archivo).
- Juntar: [matrices](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matrices) → [matriz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matriz).
- Juntar: [tipografía](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tipograf%c3%ada) → [fuentes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fuentes).
- Juntar: [filter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filter) → [filtro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filtro).
- Juntar: [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post) → [http-post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-post).
- Juntar: [translate](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translate) → [traducción](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/traducci%c3%b3n).
- Juntar: [exception](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception) → [excepciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excepciones).
- Juntar: [redirect](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redirect) → [redirección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redirecci%c3%b3n).
- Juntar: [bd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bd) → [base-de-datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/base-de-datos).
- Juntar: [ia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ia) → [inteligencia-artificial](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inteligencia-artificial).

Comment: casi todo de acuerdo.. casi.. ojo, por que interface puede referirse tanto a una interfaz grafica, como a un tipo de objeto en algunos lenguajes (mira aca https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface)

Comment: @gbianchi interesante, no había caído en ello. Pues lo mismo habría que dejar _interface_ (o algún término que se use en castellano) por un lado e [tag:interfaz-gráfica] por el otro, pues _interface_ e _interfaz_ a la vez lían bastante.

Comment: ¿[tag:notificaciones], [tag:notification] y [tag:push-notification]?

Comment: interface es una palabra inglesa. Traducida a castellano es interfaz.

Comment: Podriamos normar que se use la forma singular al momento de crear etiquetas. Evitariamos un montón de duplicados.

Comment: *Juntar: interface, interfaz y interfaz-gráfica.* una cosa es un una GUI (Interfaz gráfica de usuario) y otra cosa es una interfaz como elemento de un lenguaje de programación, como las de Typescript o las de Java. Pienso que no deberían haber etiquetas para referirse a elementos de un lenguaje, sería un poco innecesario.

Comment: Tipografía y fuentes, creo que pueden ser ambiguas no? Yo tendría cuidado, especialmente con la segunda

Comment: @JheymanMejia actualmente [tag:tipografía] tiene [tag:fonts] como sinónimo... Desde marzo de 2019.

Comment: Estoy seguro de que debería ser [tag:geolocalización]. El guión se usa en etiquetas para separar 2 palabras. Este definitivamente no sería el caso (https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=Geolocalizaci%C3%B3n,geo-localizaci%C3%B3n).

Comment: @Pollo toda la razón. Actualizo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listas las siguientes (voy actualizando):

[webbrowser](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webbrowser)
[geolocalización](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geolocalizaci%c3%b3n)
[config](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/config)
[enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enlace)
[carrusel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/carrusel)
[depuración](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depuraci%c3%b3n)
[validación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validaci%c3%b3n)
[archivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/archivo)
[fuentes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fuentes)
[filtro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filtro)
[traducción](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/traducci%c3%b3n)
[excepciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excepciones)
[redirección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redirecci%c3%b3n)
[base-de-datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/base-de-datos)
[inteligencia-artificial](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inteligencia-artificial)

Quedan para otra discusion

[interfaz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interfaz) y sus derivaciones
[radio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio) en algunas preguntas se usa para radios online... habria que retagearlas segun corresponda...
[group-by](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/group-by) es un comnado estandar de sql... agrupación, es otra cosa
[session](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session) tiene orientacion de uso y aparece muchisimas mas veces que [sesiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sesiones)
[matrices](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matrices) tiene orientacion de uso, y se usa mucho mas...
[post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post) tiene orientacion de uso, se usa mucho mas, y no se en que cambia hacer http-post... hay otro tipo de post?